# Blob is created but File is not uploaded using SignedURL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using SignedURL to upload file directly to Cloud Storage without going through App Engine instances. The Process I am following is :

1. Creating a empty Object and generating a SignedURL for that Object

   ```
   Storage storage = null;

   try{

   FileInputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream("JSONFile");

   Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);

   storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

   }catch(IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();

   }

   Acl aclObject = Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(),Role.OWNER);

   List<Acl> aclAccess = new ArrayList<>();

   aclAccess.add(aclObject);

   //BucketName and User name are Strings.
   BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME,USER_NAME+"TeamLogo");

   BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setAcl(aclAccess).setContentType("image/jpeg").build();

   Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo);
   ```

By now , An Empty Object is created in Cloud Storage

[image: Object created in Cloud Storage]

I am generating a signedURL for this Empty Object such that when user uploads a file , the Content of the file replaces the Empty object

```
    HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.PUT;

    ServiceAccountSigner signer = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder().setClientId(CLIENT_ID).setClientEmail(CLIENT_EMAIL).setPrivateKey(PRIVATEKEY).setPrivateKeyId(PRIVATE_KEY_ID).build()

    URL url = blob.signUrl(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(httpMethod),Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith(signer),Storage.SignUrlOption.withContentType());
    return url;
```

My HTML code to handle the Upload of the File

```html
<form action="${signedURL}" method="put" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Enter Your User Name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="UserName" ><br><br>
<label>Enter Your Team Name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="TeamName" ><br><br>
<label>Upload Team Logo</label><br>
<input type="file" name="myFile" required="required"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create Team">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost:8080/register">
</form>
```

After selecting the file and Clicking on Upload, the file I selected is not uploaded to Cloud Storage and it is loading this page ( A white page with a URL).

[image: Output Image]

I am not achieving my desired result. What I am missing in my Code ? Java Documentation for Cloud Storage doesn't offer full picture for newbies like me. Someone please help me in this regard.

**UPDATE : Javascript AJAX Request to Cloud Storage**

```js
var signedURL;
function uploadFile(){
    var urlxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //To get the SignedURL from server side
    urlxhr.open('GET','http://localhost:8080/getsignedurl')
    urlxhr.send();
    urlxhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (urlxhr.readyState == 4 && urlxhr.status == 200) { 
            signedURL = urlxhr.responseText;
            var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('imageFile',file);
            var storageXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            storageXhr.open('PUT',signedURL,true);
            storageXhr.onload = () => {
                if(storageXhr.status == 200){
                    alert("File Successfully Uploaded");
                }else{
                    alert("Something went Wrong");
                }
            };
            storageXhr.onerror = () => {
                alert("An Error occured while Uploading file");
            };
            storageXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',file.type);
            storageXhr.send(formData);
        }
    }

    


}
```

```html
<!-- Uploading Directly to Cloud storage by AJAX Request -->
<form action="#" method="put" onsubmit="uploadFile()">
<label>Select Your Team Logo</label>
<input type="file" id="myFile" required="required">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the [POST Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object) command but using the [PUT Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload) command. For example, you're using the `success_action_redirect`, which is only a thing for the POST object command. The PUT Object command doesn't accept form-data in this fashion.

You can use the PUT object command with a signed URL, but not in this fashion. Instead, you'd use JavaScript to craft an upload of a file's contents.

The POST object command is the one you want if you plan to use an HTML form. The rules for signing those requests are a bit different, though. Check out the "policy document" section of the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples

So, to change the example above, switch the method to `POST`, add a `policy` field and a `Signature` field that is crafted by the server the same way you're signing your requests now, and switch the action to 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name'.

Comment: Hi Brandon , Thanks for your reply. Like you suggested , I wrote a Javascript function to upload the file to Cloud Storage but when I am making a PUT request to signedURL I generated on Server side , I am getting 404 Error from GCS.  This left me with one question . Do we really need a signedURL or  I can directly use  `https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]` as mentioned in this post [Request Endpoints XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints)

Comment: I have edited the question and added the Javascript function in my code